# menuitem doesn't show hover image

Tags: asp.net, css, menuitem

Menu items don't display the hover image option with the following code. I believe I have done the CSS correctly. Suggestions?

```
<asp:Menu ID="mnuMain" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="true" Orientation="Horizontal" runat="server">
    <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="staticmenu" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="staticmenu" />
    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="staticmenu_hover" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="staticmenu_hover" />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="20px" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" ImageUrl="~/i/nest.jpg" Selected="true" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" ImageUrl="~/i/nest.jpg" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>


.staticmenu
{

}

.staticmenu_hover
{
    background-image:url('/i/bird_popup.gif');
}
```

Comment: Could you add the outputted HTML? I'm not sure how ASP adds the ImageUrl parameter to the element. If it uses an inline style then it will always override your external CSS. If it's an img element then your background-image style will have no visible effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how ASP adds the `ImageUrl` parameter to the element. But if it uses an inline style then it will always override your external CSS, and if it's an `img` element then your `background-image` style will have no visible effect.

I would suggest including both images as `background-image` styles in your CSS, and possibly using pure CSS to manage the image state, so it'd look more like this:

```
.staticmenu
{
   background-image:url('/i/nest.jpg');
}

.staticmenu:hover
{
    background-image:url('/i/bird_popup.gif');
}
```

Also note the image URLs in your CSS will be relative to the stylesheet's location, not the location of the document (unless there is a `base` tag specified in the `head`).